# The script recorded from Jmeter has a body in encrypted format, how can i parameterize it?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I have recorded a script via Jmeter's test script recorder. The website belongs to the banking domain and has a simple web form which i have to fill and click on submit button, that's it. No login is required.
The problem is when i have recorded this scenario through Jmeter test script recorder(also tried with blazemeter) the samplers have no parameters section and all the recording is done in body data tab. Since it was a web form i have obviously entered data say for 8 fields. But all i see in body data is an encrypted string(which i'm not sure is encryption or what, never encountered such thing) which looks something like below:

AB000UHrYGJ889946FGHSaiUyroDHJHFU24547878SAEHDUIYE00001644ADHWU89897EWEGHBS140045DAGWYTEvvERdnn

When i replay this it doesn't work which is understandable. Now how am i supposed to parameterize this?
Has someone encountered such scenario if so then how you have managed it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the encryption is being performed by client-side [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) so when you submit the form it calculates a [hash](https://www.tunnelsup.com/hash-analyzer/) from your input.

Depending on the hash type you can either encode the request data using JMeter's [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) or replicate the same algorithm as browser does using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: i think the __digest() is used for encoding, what i want is i want to decode that string so that i can form a body from it which may look something like : { "id" : "${my_id}", "phone no" : "${my_phn}",} so that i can parameterize it from a csv file. Is this not possible?